# Details on GitHub Actions permissions

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to find out more details about GitHub Actions permission scopes. For example, I have an action that is pulling code from the market place and it required me to add this permission:

```
...
permissions:
  pull-requests: write
...
```

I assume it's allowing write permissions to any information/meta data on the pull request. But I can't confirm this in the docs. I would love to know *exactly* what this allows as we have some security concerns about using third party actions.

Comment: This is quite vague, maybe start with https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I'll read through those more carefully. What I was hoping for was a list of what exactly each permission allows you to change. So for 'pull-requests', if you have write permission to that scope, can you change everything on the pull request? Title/description/etc. Can you close/open the pull request? Details like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitHub maintains a list of API endpoints and their required permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28). This will list all the REST APIs the token can call. The GraphQL API should enforce the same checks, but I'm not aware of a GraphQL API mapping to the permissions in the docs.

You can't manage the permissions of actions more fine-grained than `none|read|write`. If you want more assurance, you can always fork an action to your own organization and do a thorough inspection, then bring in updates from the original repository only after a new security review.

[My colleague Rob has created a set of actions that will help you stay up-to-date without automatically pulling in the latest versions of an external action](https://devopsjournal.io/blog/2021/10/14/GitHub-Actions-Internal-Marketplace).

And the [GitHub hardening guidelines for GitHub Actions also provides some guidance](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions):

- Fork actions you use to your own repo and reference them from there.
- Use the sha instead of a version or branch for extra security.
- Turn on GitHub Advanced Security for the action's repository.
- Manually inspect updates to the action prior to updating your fork.

Comment: The api list was helpful. Thanks! Basically the action code can do the api calls that require write access. So thats basically a list of the things they can do.